# Save video state after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to finish this video tutorials website, and I wanted my videos to have a coloured border depending on state and faded after finish, but it won't save after refresh.

I tried to use cookies but I can't seem to implement them. Does anyone have any idea how can I maintain the session?

```
    <iframe id="iframeul-lu-gogu"
        width="355" height="214"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3rzgrP7VA_Q?enablejsapi=1" 
        frameborder="0"
        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
        allowfullscreen
        style="border: solid 4px #37474F"
></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">

  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('iframeul-lu-gogu', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
  }
  function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
    var sloboz;
    if (playerStatus == -1) {
      sloboz = "#37474F"; // gri ca moartea
    } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
      sloboz = "#DD2C00"; // e pe stop fufa
    } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
      sloboz = "#33691E"; // mai avem nevoie si de iarba
    } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
      sloboz = "#FFFF00"; // energizant Ber Grills
    } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
      sloboz = "#AA00FF"; // strugurel
    } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
      sloboz = "#FF6DOO"; // portocala mecanica
    }
    if (sloboz) {
      document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.borderColor = sloboz;
      document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.borderWidth = "thick";
    }

  }
    function videoEndShit(playerStatus) {

    if (playerStatus == 0) {
      document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.borderWidth = "thick";  
      document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.opacity = "0.25";
      document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.transform= "rotate(0deg)";
      document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://img.heypik.com/58pic/26/26/43/58cb9f01b4a0a.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_fixed,w_355/sharpen,100/quality,q_80')";
      } else {
      document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById('iframeul-lu-gogu').style.borderWidth = "thick";
      } 
  }  

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    changeBorderColor(event.data);
    videoEndShit(event.data);
  }
</script>

<p class="subtitile">Views:

<!-- Statcounter code for licenta
file:///C:/Users/EpigonDM/Desktop/design-template/programming%20HTML.html
on Dreamweaver -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=11734579; 
var sc_invisible=0; 
var sc_security="c3ac9789"; 
var sc_text=4; 
var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
"https://secure." : "http://www.");
document.write("<sc"+"ript type='text/javascript' src='" +
scJsHost+
"statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>");
</script>
<noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="Web Analytics"
href="http://statcounter.com/" target="_blank"><img
class="statcounter"
src="//c.statcounter.com/11734579/0/c3ac9789/0/" alt="Web
Analytics"></a></div></noscript>
<!-- End of Statcounter Code -->
<a href="http://statcounter.com/p11734579/?guest=1">View My
Stats</a>


</p>


                   </div>
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone please help me" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/7571171). Sorry I can't give anything that would be of more help to you, but the question as it currently stands is difficult to answer. Please provide a [mininmal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.